# Multiple SELECT statements from different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two independent tables: 'Clients' and 'Country'.

**Country Table:**

```
IdCountry   Country
1   SPAIN
2   PORTUGAL
```

**Clients Table**

```
IdClient    Entity   IdCountry
1   Adam Alves       2
2   Peter Smith      2
3   David Ramos      1
4   Rafael Castro    1
```

I would like to add a new client into 'Clients' table but using the information from 'Country' table like this:

```
INSERT INTO Clients(IdClient, Entity, Country)
SELECT max(IdClient) + 1, '--New--' FROM Clients,
SELECT IdCountry FROM Country WHERE Country = 'SPAIN'
```

I would like to have this INPUT:

```
IdClient   Entity    IdCountry
    5      --New--   1
```

But if I run this query, it doesn't work. Could anybody help me, please?

COMMENTS: I prefer don't use autoincrement option.

Thank you very much.

Wardiam

Comment: You should do a join between Clients and Country. Can you show the Country and Clients tables ?

Comment: I updated the post

Comment: Your `client`s table doesn't have a `country` column, according to your sample data.

Comment: I updated the table now, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
INSERT INTO Clients(IdClient, Entity, Country)
SELECT 
  (SELECT MAX(IdClient) + 1 FROM Clients), 
  '--New--',
  (SELECT IdCountry FROM Country WHERE Country = 'SPAIN')
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sN2ZyhehPA1t69HTLVPjWi/1).
Results:

```
| IdClient | Entity        | Country |
| -------- | ------------- | ------- |
| 1        | Adam Alves    | 2       |
| 2        | Peter Smith   | 2       |
| 3        | David Ramos   | 1       |
| 4        | Rafael Castro | 1       |
| 5        | --New--       | 1       |
```